# Кэширование данных сервера на клиенте

Tags: c#, кэширование, синхронизация

Пишу приложение для админа. Основная задача - забрать данные с сервера, сформировать и заполнить ViewModel, отобразить списки сформированных объектов. Есть один недостаток - при первом запуске все данные (несколько коллекций, некоторые с большим количеством элементов) нужно запросить с сервера, что занимает значительное время. (Сейчас порядка 20 секунд, но в релизной версии элементов будет намного больше, и соответственно время загрузки также будет еще больше.)

Для ускорения старта приложения решил кэшировать данные, полученные с сервера на диск. (Ниже приведу примеры кода, сейчас полностью опишу свою задачу.) Создал декоратор, который умеет кэшировать данные на диск, но возникла проблема с синхронизацией кэша и данных с сервера.

Алгоритм сейчас такой:

1. Пользователь переходит на view - запускается загрузка данных в ViewModel.
2. ViewModel запрашивает данные от кэша приложения - кэш адресует запрос классу Storage - Storage загружает информацию, если она не загружена и возвращает запрашиваемую коллекцию. StorageCachingDecorator оборачивает Storage - добавляя сохранение и загрузку данных с диска. Storage имеет события для нотификации о изменении коллекции (добавление, обновление, удаление).
3. При обращении к StorageCachingDecorator он возвращает коллекцию с кеша на диске, если она есть и запускает загрузку с сервера через метод Storage (c обновлением коллекции). После чего запускается механизм сохранения коллекции на диск через заданное время.

Проблема кроется в следующем - возможна ситуация что ViewModel запросит коллекцию, начнет ее обрабатывать, но еще не подпишется на события Storage. В этот момент закончится загрузка с сервера и коллекция начнет обновляться. В результате ViewModel будет работать с старыми данными.

Проблема не всегда будет наблюдаться, но вероятность ее есть. Соответственно воспроизвести и пофиксить ее будет труднее.

Сейчас как таковой синхронизации нет вообще. Есть идея - ввести два флага: 1 - показывает есть ли ViewModel, которая загружает данные; 2 - есть ли коллекция, загружающаяся с сервера. Если флаг 1 == true - не начинать загрузку коллекции с сервера, если флаг 2 == true - не возвращать коллекцию, пока все не будет загружено с сервера.

Теперь код, Storage и StorageCachingDecorator реализуют интерфейс IStorage.
ViewModel наследуют базовому абстрактному классу ViewModelListBase.

```
public interface IStorage<T> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, T>>
                                          where T : EntityBase
{
    event EventHandler<KeyValuePair<int, T>> ItemAdded;
    event EventHandler<KeyValuePair<int, T>> ItemUpdated;
    event EventHandler<KeyValuePair<int, T>> ItemRemoved;
    ICollection<int> Keys { get; }
    int Count { get; }
    bool IsCollectionLoaded { get; }
    ICollection<T> Values{ get; }
    T RemoveIfExists(int id);
    void AddOrUpdateIfExists(T value);
    T GetValueOrDefault(int key);
    void ClearItems();
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, T>> GetCollection(bool loadDirectlyFromServer = false);
    void LoadCollectionFrom(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, T>> source);
}
```

Из Storage, StorageCachingDecorator и ViewModel приведу только важные части.

```
public class Storage<T> : IStorage<T> where T : EntityBase
{
    // ...

    public Storage(Func<List<T>> methodToGetCollection)
    {
        this.methodToGetCollection = methodToGetCollection;
    }

    // ...

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, T>> GetCollection(bool loadDirectlyFromServer = false)
    {
        if (loadDirectlyFromServer) return this.ReloadCollectionFromServer();

        if (this.isCollectionLoaded) return this.innerStorage;

        Monitor.Enter(this.loadLock);

        if (!this.isCollectionLoaded && this.isConnected)
        {
            var items = this.methodToGetCollection();

            foreach (var t in items)
            {
                this.AddOrUpdateIfExists(t);
            }

            this.isCollectionLoaded = true;
        }

        Monitor.Exit(this.loadLock);

        return this.innerStorage;
    }
    // ...        
  }
```

С помощью комментариев показана идея синхронизации с помощью флагов 1 и 2.

```
public class StoragecachingDecorator<T> : IStorage<T> where T : EntityBase
{

    // ...
    public StoragecachingDecorator(IStorage<T> storage, string cacheFileName)
    {
        this.innerStorage = storage;
        this.cacheFileName= cacheFileName;
    }

    // ...
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, T>> GetCollection(bool loadDirectlyFromServer = false)
    {
        // Проверка загружается ли что то с сервера
        //label: if (флаг 2 == true)
        //    {
        //          Wait(timeToWait);
        //          goto label;
        //     }
        if (loadDirectlyFromServer) return this.ReloadCollectionFromServer();

        if (this.innerStorage.IsCollectionLoaded) return this.innerStorage;

        var cached = this.LoadCollectionFromcache();
        if (!object.ReferenceEquals(cached, null)) return cached;

        var collection = this.innerStorage.GetCollection();
        this.StartTimer();
        return collection;
    }

    private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, T>> LoadCollectionFromcache()
    {
        if (this.iscachedCollectionLoaded) return this.cachedCollection;

        Monitor.Enter(this.loadLock);

        if (!this.iscachedCollectionLoaded)
        {
            T[] cachedData;
            try
            {
                cachedData = this.cache.Get<T[]>(this.connectedServerCode, this.cacheFileName);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                cachedData = null;
            }

            if (!object.ReferenceEquals(cachedData, null) && cachedData.Any())
            {
                this.cachedCollection = cachedData.ToDictionary(data => data.Id);
                this.innerStorage.LoadCollectionFrom(cachedCollection);

                // Вместо this.innerStorage.GetCollection(true) вставить
                // метод, который проверяет флаг 1
                // WaitableLoadCollectionFromServer()


                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.innerStorage.GetCollection(true)).GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(this.StartTimer);
                this.iscachedCollectionLoaded = true;
            }
        }

        Monitor.Exit(this.loadLock);

        return this.cachedCollection;
    }

    private  void WaitableLoadCollectionFromServer()
    {
        label: if (флаг 1 == true)
            {
                Wait(timeToWait);
                goto label;
            }

        // флаг 2 == true 
        this.innerStorage.GetCollection(true);
        // флаг 2 == false для данного T
    }    

    private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, T>> ReloadCollectionFromServer()
    {
        this.StoptTimer();
        var data = this.innerStorage.GetCollection(true);
        this.StartTimer();
        return data;
    }

    private void StartTimer()
    {
        this.timer = new Timer(this.UpdatecacheHandler, null, TimeoutToUpdatecache, TimeoutToUpdatecache);
    }

    private void StoptTimer()
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(this.timer, null)) return;

        this.timer.Dispose();
        this.timer = null;
    }

    private void UpdatecacheHandler(object state)
    {
        var dataTocache = this.innerStorage.Values.ToArray();

        if (!this.isConnected) return;

        this.cache.Set(dataTocache, pathTocacheFile);
    }
   }
```

Базовая вью модель для отображения данных.

```
public abstract class ViewModelListBase<T>
{
    public ObservableCollection<T> ItemsCollection
    {
        get { return this.itemsCollection; }

        set
        {
            this.itemsCollection = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("ItemsCollection");
        }
    }

    // ....
    public abstract void ReloadData(bool loadDirectlyFromServer);

    protected void ReloadDataAsync(Action loadDataAction, Action loadCompletedCallback)
    {
        if (!ViewModelListBase.ConnectedToServer || this.reloadDataAsyncProcessing)
        {
            return;
        }
        // Установить флаг 1 в true.
        this.reloadDataAsyncProcessing = true;            

        Task.Factory.StartNew(loadDataAction).GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(
            () =>
                {
                    this.IsDataLoaded = true;
                    this.reloadDataAsyncProcessing = false;
                    loadCompletedCallback();
                    // Установить флаг 1 в false для текущей ViemModel
                });
    }
   }
```

ViewModel, которая отображает данные.

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelListBase<ClassToShow>
{
    public override void ReloadData(bool loadDirectlyFromServer)
    {
        this.ReloadDataAsync(
            () =>
            {
                // storage - кэш приложения, построенный на Storage и StoragecachingDecorator
                // Загрузка нужных объектов в кэш. Эти объекты будут нужны при создании ViewModel для отображения 
                // в текущем View
                // Storage<ClassA>.IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, ClassA>> GetCollection();
                //
                // Некоторые классы будут использоваться при открытии редактора - будут использоваться прямо из кэша.
                // В кэше данные обновляются при обработке нотификации с сервера.
                //
                //
                this.storage.Get_ClassA_Collection(); 
                this.storage.Get_ClassB_Collection();
                this.storage.Get_ClassC_Collection();
                this.storage.Get_ClassD_Collection();                    

                // Выполняем некоторую обработку.

                var models = new List<ClassToShow>();
                models.AddRange(
                    this.storage.Get_ClassToShow_Collection(loadDirectlyFromServer).Select(
                        с => this.CreateViewModel(с.Value)));

                this.Sync(
                    () =>
                    this.itemsCollection.AddRange(
                        models.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id)));

                // Подписываемся на изменение коллекций, которые нужно отображать в текущем view.
                this.storage.Get_ClassToShow_Collection.ItemAdded += this.ClassToShowAddedHandler;
                this.storage.Get_ClassToShow_Collection.ItemRemoved += this.ClassToShowRemovedHandler;
                this.storage.Get_ClassToShow_Collection.ItemUpdated += this.ClassToShowUpdatedHandler;
                this.storage.Get_ClassA_Collection.ItemUpdated += this.ClassAUpdatedHandler;
                this.storage.Get_ClassC_Collection.ItemUpdated += this.ClassCUpdatedHandler;
                this.storage.Get_ClassC_Collection.ItemAdded += this.ClassCAddedHandler;
            },
            () =>
            {
                // Некоторая работа.
            });
    }
  }
```

Даже если использовать синхронизацию на основе флагов 1 и 2 все равно есть шанс, что что-то отработает криво. Соответственно и ценность такой синхронизации не большая. (Механизм с флагами приведен в схематическом виде - могут быть ошибки).

Если есть хороший материал по теме - буду благодарен за ссылку.

Comment: *кэш пишется как ca**c**he!*

Comment: Если обработка простая - надо вместо сохранения и обработки данных обрабатывать их каждый раз, не храня нигде кроме Storage.

Comment: Обработка простая и объекта A делается ViewModelA. Для установки некоторых полей нужны другие объекты. Проблема в том, что количество объектов А несколько тысяч (иногда несколько десятков тысяч). Также нужно отслеживать изменение коллекции объектов А на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

Как то все сложно получается.

Кaк я вижу решение, если правильно понял суть:

Ввести поле LastEditTime для редактируемых объектов.
Соответственно помечать локальный кеш как Max(LastEditTime).
С сервака забирать только дельту. И надо контролировать целостность кеша на всякий случай. Соответственно, когда происходит submit на сервер, если LstEditTime изменился  (серверный отличается от того, что ты привел на сабмит) идет reject операции.

Comment: Такая идея тоже есть. Сейчас жду когда на стороне сервера будут реализованы функции, позволяющие забрать дельту. Если лучшего решения не найду - остановлюсь на таком варианте.